# Parallels + Visual Studio 2015 only build in iPhone 4S

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

Someone is having this problem too?
Using "Parallels + Windows 10 + Visual Studio 2015," and it just runs the iPhone 4S, even choosing the iPhone 5S in Visual Studio it just makes the build in iPhone 4S, have no idea what is?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to hear about your trouble. From your post, I believe the problem is that you need to select a different target than the iPhone 4s - and the way you change that is by selecting a different option in this drop down menu.

[image: Debug Target Drop Down Menu]

Please let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not :(
I select the iPhone 5S, it performs normal in the "remotebuild" but only opens the iPhone 4S simulator.

http://i.stack.imgur.com/NgypZ.jpg

Comment: I see. Thanks for reporting this. I will file a bug and have the team investigate.

Comment: I checked with the team and the reason this is happening is because of a change in the ios-sim package. Can you try installing version 3 of the ios-sim package by running: npm install –g ios-sim@3.x

Comment: Wow, what a boring :( just left the VS 2015.
But if I install 3x lose several feature of version 4x :(